# Using cjoint to produce tables in LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, cjoint

I’m using `cjoint` package for the first time to analyze the results of a conjoint experiment I ran f few years ago. I’m able to produce the table in my R console, but does anyone know how I can produce the table in LaTeX, e.g. with `texreg()`? I’m copying my code below.

```
Women_Committee_women <- amce(
  picked_A ~ A_female + A_reserved_seat + A_edu + A_prev_exp + A_married + 
    B_female + B_reserved_seat + B_edu + B_prev_exp + B_married,
  data=Women_Committee_what_women_think,
  cluster=TRUE,
  respondent.id="ID",
  design=candidate_design
)
```